# Reledmac: in-text Bible verse numbers

Tags: line-numbering, reledmac

A nice little [macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468970/bible-verse-numbers-in-margin-with-reledmac) on `reledmac` allows replace line numbers with verse numbers. This is particularly useful for Bible verse. My question elaborates on this feature of reledmac. What should I do if, in the same environment, I want to the verse numbers in the text body and not on the side? To be clear, I don't need any text on the side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[total={2.5in, 2.7in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}%Not resetting line number annotation
\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}}%Biblical verse are managed as line annotation
\makeatletter
\Xwraplinenumannotation{\@firstofone}%We just typeset the annotation, without any formatting
\renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]{}% We don't typeset the real line number.
\makeatother
\Xnoidenticallinenumannotation% Don't typeset to identical line number annotation
\begin{document}
  \firstlinenum{1}
  \linenumincrement{1}
  \beginnumbering
  \pstart
    \bv{4}[\textbf{4}] Baptizabat Ioannes in solitudine, et emendationis vitae baptisma publicabat ad peccatorum veniam,\bv{5} [\textbf{5}] ad eumque proficiscebatur tota Iudaea regio ac Hierosolymitani, et ab eo baptizabantur omnes in Iordane fluvio, confitentes peccata sua.\bv{6} [\textbf{6}] Erat autem Ioannes indutus camelinis pilis, lateribus pelliceo cingulo cinctis, vescebaturque locustis et \edtext{melle silvestri}{\Afootnote{quod mel Ioannes non in horto vel apiario colebat, sed in locis desertis inveniebat.}},\bv{7} [\textbf{7}] atque huiusmodi verbis publice docebat: “Venit quidam post me, adeo me praestantior, ut ego non sim dignus qui eius calceorum corrigiam pronus solvam.\bv{8} [\textbf{8}] Ego quidem vos aqua baptizavi, at is vos sancto Spiritu baptizabit.”
  \pend
  \endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as you verse in the main text are the same as the annotation, you could modifiy your `\bv` command to typeset directly the verse within the bracket. 
 `\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}[\textbf{#1}]}%`.

For you main problem, you can use `Xwraplinenumannotationside` with the `\@gobble` macro.

So general document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[total={2.5in, 2.7in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}%Not resetting line number annotation
\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}[\textbf{#1}]}%Biblical verse are managed as line annotation
\makeatletter
\Xwraplinenumannotation{\@firstofone}%We just typeset the annotation, without any formatting
\Xwraplinenumannotationside{\@gobble}
\renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]{}% We don't typeset the real line number.
\makeatother
\Xnoidenticallinenumannotation% Don't typeset to identical line number annotation
\begin{document}
  \firstlinenum{1}
  \linenumincrement{1}
  \beginnumbering
  \pstart
    \bv{4} Baptizabat Ioannes in solitudine, et emendationis vitae baptisma publicabat ad peccatorum veniam,\bv{5}  ad eumque proficiscebatur tota Iudaea regio ac Hierosolymitani, et ab eo baptizabantur omnes in Iordane fluvio, confitentes peccata sua.\bv{6}  Erat autem Ioannes indutus camelinis pilis, lateribus pelliceo cingulo cinctis, vescebaturque locustis et \edtext{melle silvestri}{\Afootnote{quod mel Ioannes non in horto vel apiario colebat, sed in locis desertis inveniebat.}},\bv{7}  atque huiusmodi verbis publice docebat: “Venit quidam post me, adeo me praestantior, ut ego non sim dignus qui eius calceorum corrigiam pronus solvam.\bv{8}  Ego quidem vos aqua baptizavi, at is vos sancto Spiritu baptizabit.”
  \pend
  \endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Maïeul, it works quite well, with one exception. I've noticed in the output file that the verse number is directly attached to a punctuation mark (a period, a comma, etc.). This becomes problematic if I add a space after the punctuation mark, as the verse number and the beginning of the verse may end up on different pages. How can I fix this?

Comment: that is not related to your initial question. YOu can use `~` to have a not breakable space.