# Custom text anchor

Tags: multicolumn, text, anchor

**TL;DR: How do I achieve what's in the picture in Latex?**

I am working on a personal manuscript of scripture, where I am stripping Biblical text of all chapter/verse markings, punctuation, etc. and adding my own. However, I would still like to maintain a reference to the original verse markings. I would like to be able to typeset this in Latex, but I don't how to accomplish what I envision.

Here's what I envision the final rendered text looking like:

[image]

...where there are two columns: the right col containing the body of the text and the left col containing verse anchors (in light gray).

I imagine the source code looking something like this:

```
\verse{1}In the beginning when God created the heavens and the earth,
\verse{2}the earth was a formless void and darkness covered the face of the deep, while a wind from God swept over the face of the waters.
\verse{3}Then God said, "Let there be light"; and there was light.
\verse{4}And God saw that the light was good; and God separated the light from the darkness.
\verse{5}God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And there was evening and there was morning, the first day.
\verse{6}And God said, "Let there be a dome in the midst of the waters, and let it separate the waters from the waters."
\verse{7}So God made the dome and separated the waters that were under the dome from the waters that were above the dome. And it was so.
\verse{8}God called the dome Sky. And there was evening and there was morning, the second day.
\verse{9}And God said, "Let the waters under the sky be gathered together into one place, and let the dry land appear." And it was so.
\verse{10}God called the dry land Earth, and the waters that were gathered together he called Seas. And God saw that it was good.
```

...where some sort of custom environment or something is defined so that Latex knows where to put the anchor point. Note that I would like a reference for every 5th verse, but I'm not sure if Latex can handle that. I can easily account for that by only putting in the needed verse anchors.

**TL;DR: How do I achieve what's in the picture in Latex?**

**UPDATE:** I've checked out the lineno package which can number lines in the margin, and even skip by 5's. Unfortunately, verses and lines do not have a 1:1 correspondence, and lineno's counter can't be manually set within paragraphs, according to the user manual.

Comment: Use \marginpar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw in the `\hangindent` to distinguish the start of each verse.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\renewcommand{\verse}[1]{\par\hangindent=1em\noindent
  \ifnum 0=\numexpr #1-#1/5*5\relax \llap{#1\quad}\fi}

\begin{document}

\verse{1}In the beginning when God created the heavens and the earth,
\verse{2}the earth was a formless void and darkness covered the face of the deep, while a wind from God swept over the face of the waters.
\verse{3}Then God said, "Let there be light"; and there was light.
\verse{4}And God saw that the light was good; and God separated the light from the darkness.
\verse{5}God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And there was evening and there was morning, the first day.
\verse{6}And God said, "Let there be a dome in the midst of the waters, and let it separate the waters from the waters."
\verse{7}So God made the dome and separated the waters that were under the dome from the waters that were above the dome. And it was so.
\verse{8}God called the dome Sky. And there was evening and there was morning, the second day.
\verse{9}And God said, "Let the waters under the sky be gathered together into one place, and let the dry land appear." And it was so.
\verse{10}God called the dry land Earth, and the waters that were gathered together he called Seas. And God saw that it was good.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent! This solves the question as I had posed it. To further my Latex knowledge, would you be willing to breakdown what's going on in lines 4-5?

Comment: Is it possible to modify this so that `\verse{}` could optionally contain chapter information (e.g. `\verse{1:1}`)? Sometimes I feel like there is an unnatural break in Biblical chapters, and I would now like the verse numbers to contain chapter information when the chapter changes. For example:
```\verse{1:1} text...
\verse{2} text...
\verse{3} text..
...
\verse{2:1} text...
\verse{2} text...
\verse{3} text..``` Let's not worry about skipping by 5.
Not sure how to modify your code to accomplish this, due to my inexperience with Latex.

Comment: ^^ Nevermind, I figured it out. Simple take out the if statement: `\renewcommand{\verse}[1]{\par\hangindent=1em\noindent\llap{#1\quad}}`

Comment: Last question: is it possible to put text in the margin without starting a new paragraph? And if two verses appear on the same line, to comma separate them?

For example: `\verse{1} short amount of text \verse{2} short amount of text` shouldn't have separate paragraph for each, but should have `1, 2` in the margin

Comment: Possible, but much more difficult.  \marginpar{1} ... \marginpar{2} would but 1 and 2 in the marginpar area (using reverse marginpar) but not on the same line.  One could construct a comma delimited list, but determining when the line ends is difficult.  One way is to modify the (incredibly compicated) \output routine.  Another is to use the aux file,

Comment: No worries. I actually found your marginmerge idea after some extensive googling: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305022/how-can-i-put-marginnotes-next-to-each-other

The difficulty I had with it was that if the `\marginmerge{}` appears first on a new line, the number is placed one the margin, one line above where it should be. I could fix this by adding a zero-width joiner before `\marginmarge`, but it got tedious. I ended up finding this solution using reledmac well which is working so far: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500241/reledmac-in-text-bible-verse-numbers/500337