# How to force line number annotations on inner margin in reledmac?

Tags: reledmac

I am typesetting an old Bible. The verse numbers should be in the inner margin. I followed the advice from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500241/reledmac-in-text-bible-verse-numbers), and it works. However, it always puts the line number annotations in the left margin, whether or not it is the inner or outer margin. How do I make it always put the verse numbers in the inner margin?

Comment: please provide a MWE, in all case !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line number annotation are annotations to the line number. So, setting the line number position will set the line number annotations. You can do it using `\linenummargin` (§ 5.3.4 of the handbook), you can also set the side note margin usinge `\sidenotemargin` (§ 12.1).

So

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in,inner=1.in,outer=1.25in,top=0.6in,bottom=0.6in,heightrounded,marginpar=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}}
\makeatletter
\Xwraplinenumannotation{\@firstofone}
\renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]{}
\makeatother
\Xnoidenticallinenumannotation
\linenummargin{inner}
\sidenotemargin{outer}
\begin{document}

sss
\newpage
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large Chapter I}\par
\textit{\scriptsize The pedegree of Jesus, to shew that he is Christ, promised to *  Abraham and * David. 18. That he was conceived and borne of a Virgin, as Esay prophesied of him.}\par
\end{center}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
The \bv{1} booke of the * \ledsidenote{\scriptsize \flushleft This Goſpel is moſt ſolemly ſung in holy Church at Matins upon Chriſtmas day.} generation of  {\scshape Jesus}  Christ, the ſonne of David, the ſonne of Abraham.\par
†\bv{2}* \ledsidenote{\scriptsize \flushleft As alſo it is the Goſpel of the \textbf{\emph{Conception}} and \textbf{\emph{Nativitie}} of our Blessed Lady: becauſe here is declared the pedegree of her alſo.} Abraham begat Iſaac, And Iſaac begat Jacob. And Jacob begat Judas and his brethren/par
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```