# How do I have margin notes on the outer margin and verse numbers on the inner margin?

Tags: marginpar, marginnote, reledmac

I am trying to typeset an old Bible ([the 1582 Rheims New Testament](https://archive.org/details/1610A.d.DouayOldTestament1582A.d.RheimsNewTestament_176/page/n2101) like below). The text is in paragraph form, with the verses on the inner margin and comments and references on the outer margin. I have tried \marginpar and \marginnotes. However, having margin notes on different sides in the same paragraph and constantly switching does not work, it seems.

For example, I tried this:

```
\marginpar[1]When\marginpar{The holy feaſt of the \textit{Epiphanie} called \textit{Twelfth-day} the 6 of Januarie. upon which day this is the Goſpel.} {\scshape Jesus} therfore was *\marginnote{Luc. 2:7.} borne in Bethlehem in Juda in the dayes of Herod the King, behold, there came Sages from the Eaſt to Hieruſalem, \dagger{}\marginpar[2] ſaying, where is he that is borne King of the Jewes?
```

The problem is that the verse numbers (1 and 2) appear not on the inner margin but on the outer margin with the other text. Except for the first verse, every verse number corresponds to a dagger and needs to be aligned to it on the inner margin.

I tried the solution from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468970/bible-verse-numbers-in-margin-with-reledmac), and it works well. Except, once I use it to put a verse number in the inner margin, it messes up the margin notes right after it, making them disappear.

For example:

```
The \bv{1} booke of the * \marginpar{This Goſpel is moſt ſolemly ſung in holy Church at Matins upon Chriſtmas day.} generation of  {\scshape Jesus}  Christ, the ſonne of David, the ſonne of Abraham.\par †\bv{2}* \marginpar{As alſo it is the Goſpel of the \textbf{\emph{Conception}} and \textbf{\emph{Nativitie}} of our Blessed Lady: becauſe here is declared the pedegree of her alſo.} Abraham begat Iſaac,
```

The 1 is placed where it should be, as in the image below, but the "This Goſpel is..." disappears, instead of being below the previous margin note in the outer margin.

If you can help me figure this out, I would really appreciate it.

Edit: here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in,inner=1.in,outer=1.25in,top=0.6in,bottom=0.6in,heightrounded,marginpar=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}}
\makeatletter
\Xwraplinenumannotation{\@firstofone}
\renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]{}
\makeatother
\Xnoidenticallinenumannotation

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large Chapter I}\par
\textit{\scriptsize The pedegree of Jesus, to shew that he is Christ, promised to
*\marginpar{\scriptsize \flushleft The {\scshape first} part of this Goſpel, of the Infancie of our Saviour Christ.}
Abraham and * David. 18. That he was conceived and borne of a Virgin, as Esay prophesied of him.}\par
\end{center}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
The \bv{1} booke of the 
*\marginpar{\scriptsize \flushleft This Goſpel is moſt ſolemly ſung in holy Church at Matins upon Chriſtmas day.}
generation of  {\scshape Jesus}  Christ, the ſonne of David, the ſonne of Abraham.\par
†\bv{2}* \marginpar{\scriptsize \flushleft As alſo it is the Goſpel of the \textbf{\emph{Conception}} and \textbf{\emph{Nativitie}} of our Blessed Lady: becauſe here is declared the pedegree of her alſo.} Abraham begat Iſaac, And Iſaac begat Jacob. And Jacob begat Judas and his brethren/par
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image: How the text, margin notes, and verses are handled in the 1582 Rheims New Testament.]

[image: PDF output of what I am trying to create]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so others can compile it and see exactly what's wrong? It will be easier to help!

Comment: Sure! Here is the link! https://dpaste.org/wKBM

Comment: please pastebin it directly in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

normal `\marginnote` does not work with reledmac (it is explained in the handbook).

You may use `\ledsidenote`

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in,inner=1.in,outer=1.25in,top=0.6in,bottom=0.6in,heightrounded,marginpar=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}}
\makeatletter
\Xwraplinenumannotation{\@firstofone}
\renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]{}
\makeatother
\Xnoidenticallinenumannotation
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large Chapter I}\par
\textit{\scriptsize The pedegree of Jesus, to shew that he is Christ, promised to *\marginpar{\scriptsize \flushleft The {\scshape first} part of this Goſpel, of the Infancie of our Saviour Christ.}  Abraham and * David. 18. That he was conceived and borne of a Virgin, as Esay prophesied of him.}\par
\end{center}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
The \bv{1} booke of the * \ledsidenote{\scriptsize \flushleft This Goſpel is moſt ſolemly ſung in holy Church at Matins upon Chriſtmas day.} generation of  {\scshape Jesus}  Christ, the ſonne of David, the ſonne of Abraham.\par
†\bv{2}* \ledsidenote{\scriptsize \flushleft As alſo it is the Goſpel of the \textbf{\emph{Conception}} and \textbf{\emph{Nativitie}} of our Blessed Lady: becauſe here is declared the pedegree of her alſo.} Abraham begat Iſaac, And Iſaac begat Jacob. And Jacob begat Judas and his brethren/par
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Of course, you will have to adapt your geometry, because now the notes overlap, but that is another problem.

Comment: Thank you. However, how do I do this without messing up the notes? (They overlap now)

Comment: see next question. But please validate / vote up on this answer.